# Server IP blacklisted by RBL's

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365, blacklist

I'm using office365 mail for my domain Eg. "apples.com". The IP address is blacklisted, i think only the Microsoft support can de-list it from RBL's.
Also after looking at the email header it looks like the emails sent are routed through different servers(IP Addresses) internally by office365 and finally delivered to external recipient mailbox.i think it is also same with google apps

Is it possible to monitor blacklists for office365 mail servers ip addresses or the microsoft company will monitor themselves and delist after getting blacklisted after some time ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have to prove domain/server/ip ownership in order to ask for delisting. 
Each time I had to ask for delist for one of my customers I was never asked for any details that just the owner may know.
Of course if you pay such an high level service provider you should expect them to handle these type of issues instantly!
Also please consider that mail administrators use to ask for delist **after** they find and fix the spammer(s) source(es).
In big environments such as Azure, Google's, etc., they should be able to respond very quickly to such issues.
As for monitoring multiple RBLs at once I use [valli.org](http://multirbl.valli.org); it's not complete but lists all main RBLs as far as I know. You will be able to setup your checks through a web page change monitor such as visualping.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any global rule; it depends entirely on the RBL. For example:

- [SpamCop](https://www.spamcop.net/bl.shtml) has time-based blacklisting: the listing stops automatically a period after reports stop.
- Spamhaus has [web based self-removal](https://www.spamhaus.org/lookup/) for some of the lists, time-based removal for some.
- SORBS has manual and semi-automated [de-listings](http://www.sorbs.net/delisting/overview.shtml), but only when the problem is solved.
- For more, there's a [Comparison of DNS blacklists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_DNS_blacklists) in Wikipedia: see column *Listing lifetime*.

Because there are so many variations on how easily you can get on a RBL and how long it takes before you get de-listed, the administrator of the receiving mail system must decide how aggressive they want to be in fighting SPAM. If they have decided to be very aggressive, you must contact them and persuade them to reconsider the issue because of false positives. That's not the responsibility of the RBL service provider: they have documented how the listing works and how it should be used.

In this day and age we have [SPF](http://www.openspf.org/), [DKIM](http://www.dkim.org/) and [DMARC](https://dmarc.org/). Therefore, the usefulness of many RBLs has decreased. I'd suggest using only RLB's that lists IP addresses most certainly only used for SPAM, and on time-based listing only the ones with active removal.